# list the file and its base directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have some files in my folder /home/sample/* * /*.pdf and *.doc and * .xls etc ('**' means some sub-sub directory.

I need the shell script or linux command to list the files in following manner.

```
pdf_docs/xx.pdf  
documents/xx.doc  
excel/xx.xls
```

pdf_docs, documents and excel are directories, which is located in various depth in /home/sample. like

```
/home/sample/12091/pdf_docs/xx.pdf  
/home/sample/documents/xx.doc  
/home/excel/V2hm/1001/excel/xx.xls
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for i in {*.pdf,*.doc,*.xls}; do find /home/sample/ -name "$i"; done | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1) "/" $NF}'
```

I ve added a line of awk which will print the last 2 fields (seperated by '/' ) of the result alone

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
for i in {*.pdf,*.doc,*.xls}; do
    find /home/sample/ -name "$i";
done | perl -lnwe '/([^\/]+\/[^\/]+)$/&&print $1'
```

Comment: hi @Timofey Stolbov, It's working perfect. But, it's display the whole path of the file. i need to display the file and it's first level base directory only. "/home/sample/documents/xx.doc" (actually i got) => "documents/xx.doc" (i need this only).

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
find /home/sample -type f -regex '^.*\.\(pdf\|doc\|xls\)$'
```

Comment: thanks @shinkou. Yes, it's working good. But i need to display some other manner. please read the @Timofey Stolbov comment section.

Comment: Then simply change to the directory you want to work before doing the find command.  (i.e. cd /home/sample && find ./ -type f -regex '^.*\.\(pdf\|doc\|xls\)$')

Answer (score 0):

Takes into account spaces in file names, potential case of extension

```
for a in {*.pdf,*.doc,*.xls}; do find /home/sample/ -type f -iname "$a" -exec basename {} \; ; done
```

**EDIT**
Edited to take into account only files

Comment: thanks @Bruce. You'r very near to my requirement. Your suggestion only display the files, i need to display files and it's first level directory only.

Comment: Well, that was an unclear requirement. Can you have pdf in documents folder? I thought you wanted to display them sorted by extension

Comment: No. Actually i need to display the file with its first level directory only. Not the full path. your code display the file name only (xx.pdf, xx.doc, xx.xls). But, i need (pdf_docs/xx.pdf, documents/xx.doc, excel/xx.xls)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call out to an external program to chop the pathname like you're looking for:

```
$ filename=/home/sample/12091/pdf_docs/xx.pdf
$ echo ${filename%/*/*}
/home/sample/12091
$ echo ${filename#${filename%/*/*}?}
pdf_docs/xx.pdf
```

So,

```
find /home/sample -name \*.doc -o -name \*.pdf -o -name \*.xls -print0 |
while read -r -d '' pathname; do
  echo "${pathname#${pathname%/*/*}?}"
done
```